# Case Operator with null Handle in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to handle `LIKE` in `CASE` operator `@parameter` is not null...

```
   AND isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'')=(CASE WHEN isnull(@NatureOfShipment,'') = '' THEN isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'')  ELSE '%'+@NatureOfShipment+'%'   END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script

```
AND isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'') Like (CASE WHEN isnull(@NatureOfShipment,'') = '' THEN isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'') ELSE '%'+@NatureOfShipment+'%' END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `case` you may use `OR`

```
 AND (
  (isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'')= '') 
  or 
  (isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'') = '%'+@NatureOfShipment+'%') 
 )
```

Or

You may use `like` instead of `=` in your query

```
 AND isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'') like (CASE WHEN isnull(@NatureOfShipment,'') = '' THEN isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'') ELSE '%'+@NatureOfShipment+'%' END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you mean something like this.

```
AND isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'') = CASE WHEN isnull(@NatureOfShipment,'') = '' THEN isnull(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'') WHEN cd.CD_NatureOfShip like '%'+@NatureOfShipment+'%' then cd.CD_NatureOfShip else '' END
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you want

```
AND ISNULL(cd.CD_NatureOfShip,'') =
  COALESCE (@NatureOfShipment, cd.CD_NatureOfShip, '%'+@NatureOfShipment+'%' )
```